# Creating block circulant matrix from array N^2-by-N in Matlab codes

Tags: matlab

How can i create a circulant block matrix from a N^2-by-N array. I am trying to write a 2D  convolution in MatLab codes. I have gotten it up to forming an N^2-by-N.The problem is  to create a block matrix N-by-N from the N^2-by-N array, then form a ciculant matrix from these blocks.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I wrote a program in Mcode to generate a 9x3 matrix which is a circulant matrix created from the rows of a 3x3 matrix. Now, the 9x3 matrix is to be broken down into three block matrices 3 x 3, and each 3 x 3 matrix is to be used to create a 9 x 9 circulant matrix. My problem is how to assign a variable to each block 3 x 3 matrix to form the 9x9 circulant matrix. I have used the 'circul' command, but the 'circul' used the colomns of the 9x3 to form 9 x 27 matrix, which is wrong. Each block  3x3 is to be used to arrive at the correct 9x9 right circulant matrix.

Comment: Can you put examples in your post to show how the matrices look like? It is difficult to understand through words only